# Using .NET SqlTypes with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm writing an application that reads from a MySQL database and migrates data into a SQL Server database. I've chosen to write this in C# because of it's built in SQL structures and functionality. I was wondering, would it be possible to use the System.Data.SqlTypes.* structures in my classes where data from MySql will be read into?

ie.

```
// Pseudo code
IDataReader reader = /* { return DB reader } */;

while (reader.Read())
{
  SqlString str = (SqlString) reader["someVarCharField"];
  SqlBoolean b = (SqlBoolean) reader["someTinyIntField"];
}
```

Will this work or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I did something very similar a few years ago, and from what I recall I just used the built-in types. No need for the Sql specific types.

Comment: The only problem is converting TinyINT to Boolean (built-in) because there is no conversion from a string of "1" to true. I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: I did use the .net types, like string, long, boolean etc. In my case, for boolean i used Ctype in vb .net. => Ctype("1", boolean)

Comment: @MarkP You can use the Convert.ToBoolean() method. http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-int-bool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the [MySqlDbType](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqldbtype) it is arguably best practice to simply do an [Explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) to a .Net type then use the correct [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) on inserting the data into SqlServer. This removes any issues with casting, null references etc.

```
string myStringField = reader["someVarCharField"].ToString();
bool myBoolField = reader.GetBoolean("booleanField");
etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking what if you just did something like,  psudeo code

inside Sql Class...

```
while(reader.Read())
{
   int id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
   string name = reader[1];
   bool active = false;
   if(int.Parse(reader[2].ToString()) == 1)
      active = true;

   SqlServerDBInsert(id, name, active);
}
```

... The insert

```
SQLServerDBInsert(int id, string name, bool active)
{

   string query = "INSERT INTO MyTable(ID, Name, Active) VALUES(@id, @name, @active)";
   using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
   {
     SqlParamter param = new SqlParameter();
     param.ParameterName = "@id";
     param.Value = id;
     param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
     ....
   }
}
```

I'm not sure about having a connection open to MySQL and SQLServer at the same time so there  is that to be worried about.